# Trace PHP file that triggered sendmail

Tags: php, monitor, mail, sendmail

Something in my system is sending mails I am not expecting.  I can see the mail items in `/var/log/mail.log` but I am very interested in figuring out exactly which file in my web application is triggering them.  Does anyone know how I can monitor this?

Comment: See if this helps - https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam .

Comment: @bodhi.zazen perhaps that should be an answer?